# on ListView item click, move Google Map camera to the specified marker

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a Google Maps activity that includes a search box and a List View of Deliveries (which hold LatLng). When I click on an address inside of the List view, I want the camera to move to that address/marker (all Addresses inside the ListView are marked).

I have this method inside of my custom ListAdapter where I tried to get Update the Camera, but it doesn't work. Here's part of my code.

```
public class DeliveriesListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Delivery> implements View.OnClickListener {
private ArrayList<Delivery> deliveries;


public DeliveriesListAdapter(ArrayList<Delivery> data, Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.activity_row_item, data);
    this.deliveries = data;
    this.mContext = context;
}
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO: on click, move camera to selected address on map.
        int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
        Delivery delivery = (Delivery) deliveries.get(position);
        CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(delivery.getLatLng());
    }
}
```

[The List at the bottom of the screen is supposed to move the camera to that marker on the map.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al0gO.png)

Here's My Data class that holds the LatLng of the specified list item.

```
public class Delivery {

private String address;
private double distance, time;
private LatLng latLng;
private Place place;

public Delivery(Place place) {
    address = place.getAddress().toString();
    distance = -1; 
    time = -1;
    latLng = place.getLatLng();
    this.place = place;
}
```

Inside of my Google Maps activity:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

private ArrayList<Delivery> deliveryList = new ArrayList<>();

// called inside onCreate(...)
  private void setUpListView() {
    deliveriesListView = findViewById(R.id.deliveries_listview);
    adapter = new DeliveriesListAdapter(addressList, this);
    deliveriesListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

/**
 * Used to add Delivery to a list view.
 * @param delivery The Delivery containing the address to be added to the view to add the marker.
 */
private void addDeliveryToList(Delivery delivery) {
    deliveryList.add(delivery);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

edit: I know that `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(delivery.getLatLng());` was wrong, I was messing with it earlier and deleted what I had originally.

**SOLUTION**: I managed to solve it by rewriting my custom list adapter to be a RecyclerViewAdapter, and managed to move the Overriden onClick method to my Maps Activity, which was what I was having trouble doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to tell map to move camera. Like this `mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(delivery.getLatLng()))`. And one more thing, you should neveer handle clicks in the adapter. They ought to be contained in the host UI part. You can use interface to have callback in the host UI part. You can get hint on how to do this [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/click-listener-for-recyclerview-adapter-2d17a6f6f6c9).

Comment: Keep a practice of accepting the answer if it solved your concern.

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCLick` function, replace `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(delivery.getLatLng());` by `animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(delivery.getLatLng())`